# powershell how to find Server name from ODBC connection

Tags: powershell

How to get the Server name, database name from ODBC DSN using PowerShell? 
When I execute PS:> Get-OdbcDSN, it shows partial Attribute string. but not full string.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change your screen/output formatting settings and or try...

```
Get-OdbcDSN | 
Select-Object -Property '*' | 
Format-List -Force
```

See also:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/using-format-commands-to-change-output-view?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Hi, I have set variable $FormatEnumerationLimit =-1. Then I executed Get-OdbcDSN | select Name, PropertyValue, Platform | Format-List.  It shows fine now.

Comment: Good deal. Many are not  or chose not to make themselves aware of all possible automatic and default variables and when to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple ps script to list out all "Attribute"

```
$dsn = Get-ODBCDSN -name "yourOdbcDsnHere" 
foreach ($attr in $dsn.Attribute) {
    Write-Output $attr
}
```

hope this help